# retrieve records where exercise_day equals current day

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have this sql table:

[image: table]

Lets say I have this query that retrieves records:

```
SELECT exercise_name, exercise_sets, exercise_reps from planner where exercise_day = 'sunday';
```

But instead of Sunday, I retrieve records from the current day.

Thank You

Comment: where is your from?

Comment: iam from iraq sir

Answer (score 2):

Use the `DAYNAME()` function.

```
WHERE exercise_day = DAYNAME(NOW())
```

You can find all the date-related functions in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: Seeing the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname), they show "Saturday" with an uppercase "S". Will that fail with their (all) lowercase values?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner MySQL defaults to case-insensitive comparisons.